# json serialization with type information

Tags: json, serialization, types

I need to transfer typed data structure into a server using JSON.
The original data is typed and I need the sever to reconstruct these typed data.

As a very simple example suppose I have the following data structure:
double pi1 = 3.14 (server must know is is double)
float  pi2 = 3.14 (server must know is is float)

I understand the json is typeless.
I also searched and saw various implementations (ex: "__type" in asp net) and can invent one myself

ex.

{ "pi1": {"type": "double", "value": 3.14},
  "pi2": {"type": "float",  "value": 3.14} }

**Is there any convention and/or efficient good practice for this or must I "invent" a type notation?**

Comment: Do you only need primitive types (or also `{type: "MyFancyStruct", value: {x:1, y:2}}`)?

Comment: fancy types too. I gave the primitives just for the example simplicity

Comment: JSON is not 'typeless', it just has few types.